# Racket maximum call depth for a function

Tags: racket

I want to write a function that figures out the maximum call stack depth required to execute another parameterless function. Let us call the desired function `call-stack-max-depth`

For example, assume that I have a recursive implementation of factorial, then

```
(call-stack-max-depth (lambda () (fac 100))
```

should return a number greater than 100. Where as with an iterative implementation of factorial, we may expect

```
(call-stack-max-depth (lambda () (fac-iter 100))
```

to return some constant, probably much less than 100.

I'm unable to write the function `call-stack-depth`. So far, I've looked at a similar question asked at [Accessing call stack depth in Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30923539/accessing-call-stack-depth-in-scheme), and attempted to modify the suggested code. I would greatly appreciate any help to get `call-stack-max-depth` to work. I think it is possible by using continuation-marks.

Comment: This information isn't available in the racket runtime by default. You'd need to do something similar to what the errortrace library does, where it registers a compilation hook that inserts code into every expression that records information in continuation marks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
(: test-call-stack-depth : Number -> Number)
(define (test-call-stack-depth max)
  (helper max 0) 
 )

(: helper : Number Number -> Number)
(define (helper max depth)
  (let ([returnVal yourFunc])
    (if returnVal
        depth
        (helper max(+ 1 depth))
     )
   )
)
```

just make sure `yourFunc` will return `true` only when the tested function have finished.
and make sure your function return a value after each iteration (the recursion will happend in the `helper` function).